# Произвольная функция в качестве слота в QObject::connect()

Tags: c++, qt

В Qt существует так называемый `QGamepadManager Class` который отвечает за подключение джойстика и получения с него сигналов при нажатии на кнопку или движения триггера.

```
GamepadMonitor::GamepadMonitor(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_gamepad(0)
{
    auto gamepads = QGamepadManager::instance()->connectedGamepads();
    if (gamepads.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    m_gamepad = new QGamepad(*gamepads.begin(), this);
    connect(m_gamepad, &QGamepad::axisLeftXChanged, this, [](double value){
        qDebug() << "Left X" << value;
    });
    connect(m_gamepad, &QGamepad::axisLeftYChanged, this, [](double value){
        qDebug() << "Left Y" << value;
    });

    connect(m_gamepad, &QGamepad::buttonAChanged, this, [](double value){
        qDebug() << "Button A" << value;
    });
}
```

Подскажите, как вместо `qDebug() << "Left X" << value;` выполнить функцию и передать в нее этот `value`?

Comment: Заменяете объявление лямбда-функции на упоминание имени обычной функции. Или ваша функция — метод класса? Тогда лямбду надо заменить на вызов `std::bind(myFunction, classPtr);`

Comment: Заменить на `f(value)` прямо в лямбде, не?

Comment: @Arhad моя функция выглядит так `minimalaladinclien.sendJoystickAxisUpdate(value);`

Comment: @Insider, тогда будет `connect(m_gamepad, &QGamepad::axisLeftXChanged, this, std::bind(&YourClass::sendJoystickAxisUpdate, minimalaladinclien);`, где `YourClass` — это тип переменной `minimalaladinclien`. И да, заголовочный файл `<functional>` включите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соедините сигнал с Вашим методом таким образом (если метод не является слотом, то сделайте его таковым):

```
 connect(m_gamepad, SIGNAL(axisLeftXChanged(double)), minimalaladinclien, SLOT(sendJoystickAxisUpdate(double));
```

Как вариант можно написать так, тогда не придётся изменять класс переменной `minimalaladinclien`:

```
connect(m_gamepad, &QGamepad::axisLeftXChanged, this, [this](double value){
    minimalaladinclien->sendJoystickAxisUpdate(value);
});
```

Ну и способ который уже предложил @Arhad, пожалуй, самый правильный, если метод не является слотом:

```
connect(m_gamepad, &QGamepad::axisLeftXChanged, this, std::bind(&YourClass::sendJoystickAxisUpdate, minimalaladinclien);
```

Функция `bind` подключается с помощью `include <functional>`

Comment: слегка ошибся на счет `minimalaladinclient`. Правильно будет `minimalaladinclient->sendJoystickAxisUpdate(value);`

Comment: и еще такой вопрос, если метод уже является слотом, что нужно?

Comment: @Insider В таком случае используйте первый вариант из моего ответа

Comment: при запуске программы происходит креш, указывает на  `connect(m_gamepad, SIGNAL(axisLeftXChanged(double)), minimalaladinclien, SLOT(sendJoystickAxisUpdate(double));`

Comment: @Insider креш на connect это странно, можно полностью код увидеть?

Comment: вот .cpp https://pastebin.com/u1kM8zi1 и .h https://pastebin.com/N0K8cgRG

Comment: креш именно происходить если джойстик включен и если происходит движение.

Comment: @Insider можно ещё класс MinimalAladinClient ?

Comment: вот тут .cpp и .h https://pastebin.com/vrxUuJsM но чтобы понять откуда берется `sendJoystickAxisUpdate` нужно скинуть весь код проекта)

Comment: @Insider Попробуйте создать любой слот в классе MinimalAladinClient и соединить его вместо sendJoystickAxisUpdate. Если всё сработает, то проблема в реализации sendJoystickAxisUpdate слота

Comment: может потому что sendJoystickAxisUpdate принимает float?

Comment: @Insider Попробуйте добавить преобразование: static_cast<float>(value)

Comment: простите куда именно его добавить?

Comment: @Insider можно в варианте через лямбду (второй пример)

Comment: если как во втором примере, то получаю -`/home/dev/test- ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
         minimalaladinclient->sendJoystickAxisUpdate(static_cast<float>(value))`  и `error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘GamepadMonitor::minimalaladinclient’
     MinimalAladinClient *minimalaladinclient;
                          ^`

Comment: @Insider Прошу прощения, сонный был, забыл захватить this. Для этого просто в квадратных скобках надо добавить this. Исправил в примере